# Filter a list of paths to only include files

Tags: file, haskell, io, path

If I have a list of `FilePaths`, how can I filter them to return only the ones that are regular files (namely, not symlinks or directories)?

For example, using `getDirectoryContents`

```
main = do
    contents <- getDirectoryContents "/foo/bar"
    let onlyFiles = filterFunction contents in
        print onlyFiles
```

where "filterFunction" is a function that returns only the `FilePaths` that represent files.

The answer may just work on Linux, but cross platform support is preferred.

[EDIT] Just using doesDirectoryExist doesn't work as expected. This script prints a list of everything in the directory, not just files:

```
module Main where

import System.Directory
import Control.Monad (filterM, liftM)

getFiles :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getFiles root = do
    contents <- getDirectoryContents root
    filesHere <- filterM (liftM not . doesDirectoryExist) contents
    subdirs <- filterM doesDirectoryExist contents
    return filesHere

main = do
    files <- getFiles "/"
    print $ files
```

Additionally, the variable subdirs will only contain `"."` and `".."`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To find standard library functions, [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a great resource; it's a Haskell search engine that lets you search *by type*.  Using it requires figuring out how to think about types the Haskell Way™, though, which your proposed type signatures doesn't quite work with.  So:

1. You're looking for `[Filepath] -> [Filepath]`.  Remember, the Haskell spelling is `FilePath`.  So…
2. You're looking for `[FilePath] -> [FilePath]`.  This is unnecessary; if you want to filter things, you should use [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter).  So…
3. You're looking for a function of type `FilePath -> Bool` that you can pass to `filter`.  But this can't quite be right: this function needs to query the file system, which is an effect, and Haskell tracks effects in the type system using `IO`.  So…
4. You're looking for a function of type `FilePath -> IO Bool`.

And [if we search for that on Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=FilePath+-%3E+IO+Bool), the first result is [`doesFileExist :: FilePath -> IO Bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:doesFileExist) from [`System.Directory`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Directory.html).  From the docs:

> The operation [`doesFileExist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:doesFileExist) returns [`True`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:True) if the argument file exists and is not a directory, and [`False`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:False) otherwise.

So `System.Directory.doesFileExist` is exactly what you want.  (Well… only with a little extra work!  See below.)

Now, how do you use it?  You can't use `filter` here, because you have an effectful function.  You could use Hoogle again – if `filter` has the type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, then annotating the results of the functions with a monad `m` gives you the new type [`Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [Bool]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=Monad+m+%3D%3E+(a+-%3E+m+Bool)+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+m+%5BBool%5D) – but there's an easier "cheap trick".  In general, if `func` is a function with an effectful/monadic version, that effectful/monadic version is called `funcM`, and it often lives in [`Control.Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html).¹  And indeed, there is a function [`Control.Monad.filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:filterM).

*However!*  Much as we hate to admit it, even in Haskell, types don't provide all the information you need.  Importantly, we're going to have a problem here:

- File paths given as arguments to functions are interpreted *relative to the current directory*, but…
- [`getDirectoryContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:getDirectoryContents) returns paths *relative to its argument*.

Thus, there are two approaches we can take to fix things.  The first is to adjust the results of `getDirectoryContents` so that they can be interpreted correctly.  (We also discarding the `.` and `..` results, although if you're just looking for regular files they won't hurt anything.)  This will return file names which include the directory whose contents are being examined.  The adjust `getDirectoryContents` function looks like this:

```
getQualifiedDirectoryContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getQualifiedDirectoryContents fp =
    map (fp </>) . filter (`notElem` [".",".."]) <$> getDirectoryContents fp
```

The `filter` gets rid of the special directories, and the `map` prepends the argument directory to all the results.  This makes the returned files acceptable arguments to `doesFileExist`.  (If you haven't seen them before, [`(System.FilePath.</>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.0.0/docs/System-FilePath-Windows.html#v:-60--47--62-) appends two file paths; and [`(Control.Applicative.<$>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--36--62-), also available as [`(Data.Functor.<$>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-), is an infix synonym for [`fmap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap), which is like [`liftM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM) but more broadly applicable.)

Putting that all together, your final code becomes:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import System.FilePath
import System.Directory

getQualifiedDirectoryContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getQualifiedDirectoryContents fp =
    map (fp </>) . filter (`notElem` [".",".."]) <$> getDirectoryContents fp

main :: IO ()
main = do
  contents  <- getQualifiedDirectoryContents "/foo/bar"
  onlyFiles <- filterM doesFileExist contents
  print onlyFiles
```

Or, if you feel like being fancy/point-free:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import System.FilePath
import System.Directory

getQualifiedDirectoryContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getQualifiedDirectoryContents fp =
    map (fp </>) . filter (`notElem` [".",".."]) <$> getDirectoryContents fp

main :: IO ()
main =   print
     =<< filterM doesFileExist
     =<< getQualifiedDirectoryContents "/foo/bar"
```

The second approach is to adjust things so that `doesFileExist` runs with the appropriate current directory.  This will return just the file name relative to the directory whose contents are being examined.  To do this, we want to use the [`withCurrentDirectory :: FilePath -> IO a -> IO a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:withCurrentDirectory) function (but see below), and then pass `getDirectoryContents` the current directory `"."` argument.  The documentation for `withCurrentDirectory` says (in part):

> Run an [`IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#t:IO) action with the given working directory and restore the original working directory afterwards, even if the given action fails due to an exception.

Putting all this together gives us the following code

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Directory

main :: IO ()
main = withCurrentDirectory "/foo/bar" $
         print =<< filterM doesFileExist =<< getDirectoryContents "."
```

This is what we want, but unfortunately, it's only available in version 1.3.2.0 of the `directory` package – as of this writing, the most recent one, and not the one I have.  Luckily, it's an easy function to implement; such set-a-value-locally functions are usually implemented in terms of [`Control.Exception.bracket :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> IO c) -> IO c`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket).  The `bracket` function is run as `bracket before after action`, and it correctly handles exceptions.  So we can define `withCurrentDirectory` ourselves:

```
withCurrentDirectory :: FilePath -> IO a -> IO a
withCurrentDirectory fp m =
  bracket getCurrentDirectory setCurrentDirectory $ \_ -> do
    setCurrentDirectory fp
    m
```

And then use this to get the final code:

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import System.Directory

withCurrentDirectory :: FilePath -> IO a -> IO a
withCurrentDirectory fp m =
  bracket getCurrentDirectory setCurrentDirectory $ \_ -> do
    setCurrentDirectory fp
    m

main :: IO ()
main = withCurrentDirectory "/foo/bar" $
         print =<< filterM doesFileExist =<< getDirectoryContents "."
```

---

Also, one quick note about `let`s in `do`s: in a `do` block,

```
do ...foo...
   let x = ...bar...
   ...baz...
```

is equivalent to

```
do ...foo...
   let x = ...bar... in
     do ...baz...
```

So your example code doesn't need the `in` in the `let` and can outdent the `print` call.

---

¹ Not always: sometimes you want different classes of effects!  Use [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) from [`Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) when possible; more things are `Applicative`s than are `Monad`s (although this means you can do less with them).  In that case, the effectful functions may live there, or also in [`Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) or [`Data.Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html).

Comment: This is one heck of an answer. Well played.

Comment: While I appreciate your answer and effort, it doesn't seem to work! Try the edited code sample I just posted (or maybe just tell me what's wrong with it if I've made an error).

Comment: @Langston: Oh jeez, I've run into that before, but I forgot!  `getDirectoryContents` returns paths that are *relative to its argument*; `doesDirectoryExist` treats paths as *relative to the current working directory*.  Sorry about that!  I'll add code to this answer which fixes that.

Comment: @AntalS-Z Please comment when you get the time to fix that, so I know :)

Comment: @Langston: Done, in a few different ways :-)  (Plus I correctly used `doesFileExist` instead of `doesDirectoryExist` – oops!)

Comment: ```map (fp </>) . filter (`notElem` [".",".."]) <$> getDirectoryContents fp``` could be squashed to `map (fp </>) <$> listDirectory fp`.  See [System.Direcotry.listDirectory](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.1.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v:listDirectory)

Answer (score 5):

For Unix systems, the package `unix` exposes these API's:

- [isRegularFile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.5.0.0/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#v:isRegularFile)
- [isSymbolicLink](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.5.0.0/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#v:isSymbolicLink)
- [isDirectory](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.5.0.0/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#v:isDirectory)

You can use the combination of them to achieve what you want. A sample demo of using them in GHCI:

```
λ> import System.Posix.Files
λ> status <- getFileStatus "/home/sibi"
λ> isDirectory status
True
λ> isRegularFile status
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library [shelly](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly). It's dedicated to do a shell scripting with Haskell. Here is the solution with shelly:

```
module Sh where

import Control.Monad
import Data.String 

import Shelly

dir = fromString "/home/me"

printAll = mapM_ print

main = do
    files <- shelly $ filterM test_f =<< ls dir
    printAll files
```

We use the functions:

ls - for listing the directory content.

```
ls :: FilePath -> Sh [FilePath]
```

test_f - for testing if the directory is a file:

```
test_f :: FilePath -> Sh Bool
```

shelly - to execute the script:

```
shelly :: MonadIO m => Sh a -> m a
```

also we use fromString to create a shelly's FilePath. There is a dedicated type it's not just a string.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to need a way to list only regular files in a directory, and this is how I do it. I thought it might be helpful:

```
import System.Directory

listFilesInDirectory :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
listFilesInDirectory dir = do
    rawList <- listDirectory dir
    filterM doesFileExist (map (dir </>) rawList)
```