# Haskell: how to make a list of files and a list of directories out of one common list

Tags: list, file, haskell, partition, io-monad

This is a newbie question. Suppose I want to separate a list of files and directories into a list of files and a list of directories:

```
getFilesAndDirs :: [FilePath] -> ([FilePath], [FilePath])
getFilesAndDirs paths =
  let ...
  in (dirs, files)
```

Probably this is a hopeless duplicate, I just miss the right keywords.
What is the right way to do (and call) this?

The files and the directories occur randomly.

Comment: There's a function in `Data.List` called `partition` that looks like what you ask for.

Comment: @MarkSeemann: I think that a problem here is that the predicate is monadic (`FilePath -> IO Bool`)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31419429/126014

Comment: n.m. is right: there's no way to know whether a path refers to a file or directory, short of actually accessing that path, which is an `IO` operation. That is, unless you're ok with a heuristic like whether there is a standard file-extension, but this wouldn't be very reliable in general.

Comment: @n.m. this just means that the type should be `getFilesAndDirs :: [FilePath] -> IO ([FilePath], [FilePath])`. I'm sure the OP will take *that* as an answer, as it is "a *newbie* question".

Comment: `partitionM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m ([a], [a])` from [`extra's Control.Monad.Extra`](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=partitionM) seems to be the ticket.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is absolutely the ticket.

Comment: (there used to be an insightful comment here by user n.m. about how if the function must do any I/O there *must* be `IO` somewhere in its type.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Data.List` package has the [**`partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition) function which splits a list of `a`s into a tuple of two lists of `a`s based on a predicate.

The problem is however that when we check if a file is a directory, we probably will use [**`isDirectory :: FilePath -> IO Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-fileio-0.1/docs/System-Directory.html) so we can not directly use this as a predicate (since `IO Bool` is not equal to `Bool`).

We can write our own `partitionM` however, and use that one:

```
import Data.Bool(bool)
import Data.Foldable(foldrM)

partitionM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> t a -> m ([a], [a])
partitionM p = foldrM (selectM p) ([],[])

selectM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> a -> ([a], [a]) -> m ([a], [a])
selectM p x (ts,fs) = p x >>= return . bool (ts, x:fs) (x:ts,fs)
```

we can then use it like:

```
import System.Directory(isDirectory)

getFilesAndDirs :: [FilePath] -> IO ([FilePath], [FilePath])
getFilesAndDirs = partitionM isDirectory
```

Note that it is an `IO ([FilePath], [FilePath])`, since we need to perform I/O to check if a path is indeed a directory (and not a file).

Comment: Aren't you missing the monad on the result type of `selectM`? Also, is the lazy pattern match worth it?

Comment: @SebastianRedl: thanks. It is indeed probably not worth it :)

Comment: While it's a matter of style, I prefer using `do` notation and to 'pull the values out of `IO`' and then pass them to pure functions. The end result is the same, but see my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `do` notation to orchestrate the impure parts of your program, and then use the built-in (pure) functions like `partition` to do the actual work. Here's an example:

```
module Q47755054 (getFilesAndDirs) where

import Data.List (partition)
import Data.Bifunctor (bimap)
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist)

tagPath :: FilePath -> IO (FilePath, Bool)
tagPath path = do
  isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist path
  return (path, isDirectory)

getFilesAndDirs :: [FilePath] -> IO ([FilePath], [FilePath])
getFilesAndDirs paths = do
  taggedPaths <- mapM tagPath paths
  return $ bimap (fmap fst) (fmap fst) $ partition snd taggedPaths
```

Notice that this uses the built-in `mapM` function to get an impure list of values (`IO [(FilePath, Bool)]`), but due to the `do` syntax and the `<-` binding, `taggedPaths` 'looks' like a pure value (`[(FilePath, Bool)]`), and therefore you can pass it to `partition`.

Notice, additionally, that `tagPath` is just a module-level helper function that isn't exported by the module.

Answer (score 0):

```
module SeparateFiles where
    import Data.String
    import System.FilePath.Posix


    type Path = FilePath
    getFilesAndDirs :: Path -> [(Path,Path)]
    getFilesAndDirs path = [splitFileName path]
```

I understand that you want to split your FilePath extracting into a file and directory. I provide you a very short example.